# Use other table than user for login authentication

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, php-5.3

For my project I have used the *student table* for authentication and storing information. For student registration all the datas are inserted in the student tale fine unlike login authentication. The attributes of the student table are `[id(primary key and auto incremented), username, password, stdname, stdage, created_at, updated_at]`.

**Registration**

```
public function post_register()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $rules = array(
        'email' => 'required|email|Between:3, 64|unique:student,username',
        'studentPass' => 'required',
        'studentName' => 'required',
        'studentAge'  => 'integer|Min:18|Max:45');
    $messages = array(
        'email.required' => 'You forgot to enter your email id!',
        'email.between'  => 'Email must be between 3 to 64 character!',
        'studentPass.required' => 'You forgot to enter your password!',
        'studentName.required' => 'You forgot to enter student name!',
        'studentAge.integer'   => 'Student age must be a integer value!',
        'studentAge.min'   => 'Student age must be a greater than 18 years!',
        'studentAge.max'   => 'Student age must be a less than value 45 years!'

    ); /* Add your custom messages here */
    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::to('register')->withErrors($validator);
    }
    else
    {
        $student = new student();
        $student->username = $input['email'];
        $student->password = $input['studentPass'];
        $student->stdname  = $input['studentName'];
        $student->stdage   = $input['studentAge'];
        $student->save();
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
}
```

**Login**

```
public function post_index()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $rules = array(
        'email' => 'required|email|Between:3, 64',
        'studentPass' => 'required');

    $messages = array(
        'email.required' => 'You forgot to enter your email id!',
        'email.between'  => 'Email must be between 3 to 64 character!',
        'studentPass.required' => 'You forgot to enter your password!'
    ); /* Add your custom messages here */

    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);

    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors($validator);
    }
    else
    {
        $credential = array('username' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['studentPass']);
        $auth = Auth::attempt($credential);
        if(Auth::attempt($credential))
            return Redirect::to('index');
        else
            return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide what do you means not working?

Answer (score 5):

In your registration page insert your password using HASH. Write the code as

```
public function post_register()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $rules = array(
        'email' => 'required|email|Between:3, 64|unique:student,username',
        'studentPass' => 'required',
        'studentName' => 'required',
        'studentAge'  => 'integer|Min:18|Max:45');
    $messages = array(
        'email.required' => 'You forgot to enter your email id!',
        'email.between'  => 'Email must be between 3 to 64 character!',
        'studentPass.required' => 'You forgot to enter your password!',
        'studentName.required' => 'You forgot to enter student name!',
        'studentAge.integer'   => 'Student age must be a integer value!',
        'studentAge.min'   => 'Student age must be a greater than 18 years!',
        'studentAge.max'   => 'Student age must be a less than value 45 years!'

    );//Add your custom messages here
    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::to('register')->withErrors($validator);
    }
    else
    {
        $password = Hash::make($input['studentPass']);
        $student = new student();
        $student->username = $input['email'];
        $student->password = $password;
        $student->stdname  = $input['studentName'];
        $student->stdage   = $input['studentAge'];
        $student->save();
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
}
```

In Laravel password must be in HASH. I think after replacing the function post_register() like that your login authentication will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

For the user registration, you need to `Hash::make($input['studentPass'])`

For the user login, you need to (A) Verify your posted password field name, and (B) auth only once... you have:

```
 $auth = Auth::attempt($credential);
 if(Auth::attempt($credential))
```

Instead, just use `if($auth)`.

Lastly, you should check your app/config/auth.php and ensure your 'driver' is set to 'eloquent'. Then make your `class User extends Eloquent` model.